# Can STM32F429IGT6 and STM32F429IIT6 be used interchangeably?

Tags: stm32

I bought a STM32F429IIT6 after reading a detailed introduction article about this device.

The problem is after I got this device I found out that I got a STM32F429IGT6 at home already, so are these two can be used interchangeably?

Comment: Yup, one just has more flash but the pinouts are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STM32F429IIT6 has 2MB of flash memory. STM32F429IGT6 has only 1MB of flash memory. Otherwise they are the same. STM32F429IGT6 is cheaper.
https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32f429-439.html